# Improving latency between developer machine and oracle db

Tags: oracle, database-performance

It seems our developers are concerned with the latency they are getting between their dev machines at site a and the database which is at site b.

Ofcourse the obvious thing is to have as little as possible hops between site a and b and make sure we have stable and speedy internet connection.

What else should be looked at to improve the latency? And what minimum spec network should they have between the developer machines and the oracle db servers. Is the spec of the server/machines important, if so what would be your recommendations?

Comment: That's a rather broad question. Please show what sort of latency are you getting? Is it pure network latency, i.e. ping latency, or application latency, i.e. plsql latency or jdbc latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And what minimum spec network should they have between the developer machines and the
>   Oracle db servers. I

The same as production. Actually they should not work on a production db at all but have a db for development only. On a separate machine. Preferably in their office.

> Is the spec of the server/machines important,

Depends on what you do on the database, but no, it will not influence latency at all.

> If so what would be your recommendations?

Something that is good enough. On my last project our development environment consisted of an ExaData cluster for about 250.000 euro - because we needed it. What you need depends on what you do, so the spec question is VERY open. THAT said: most of the time they should have a virtualization cluster and just allocate what they need for database servers for testing and development.

Answer (score 1):

If it's network latency then, depending on your budget, you could opt for  a  leased line, but that's really expensive. The capacity would depend on how much data needs to be transferred between site a and b. So you will need to measure this.